# Robson tree traversal algorithm

Tags: binary-search-tree, tree-traversal, stackless

Can anyone explain the Robson algorithm for tree traversal? I'm having trouble understanding what the steps of the algorithm are.

Comment: http://aakashpradeep.wordpress.com/tag/robson-tree-traversal/

Answer (score 0):

Do you happen to have an assignment due on 5/12 that you are trying to complete?

Robson tree traversals is just a way to traverse trees using a bunch of pointers. [The Steps Outlined Here do a very good job at outlining the procedures.](http://www.icodeguru.com/vc/10book/books/book2/algo0343.htm)

I would recommend creating a tree with pen and paper and following the steps. It's the easiest way to wrap your head around all of pointers, and what they are doing.